# Before Insert Trigger Populate Lookup Field

Tags: trigger, before-trigger

I have a very simple trigger that for some reason doesn't want to work. Using a before insert trigger, I want to populate a lookup field on a grandchild object with the grandparent objects OwnerId. When I try it, nothing happens. If you know why, can you please tell me how to fix it? Thank you.

```
trigger someName on grandChild__c (before insert){

for(grandChild__c a: trigger.new)

if(a.Approver__c == null)
{
    a.Approver__c == a.Parent__r.Grandparent__r.OwnerId;
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to query for the values of `a.Parent__r.Grandparent__r.OwnerId`as they are not available in the trigger context.

So something like

```
Map<ID,parent__c> gcMap = new Map<ID,parent__c>();

for(grandchild__c gc : trigger.new)
  gcMap.put(gc.Parent__c,null);

gcMap = New Map<ID,Parent__c>([Select Grandparent__r.OwnerId from parent__c where ID IN :gcMap.keySet()]);

for(grandchild__c gc : trigger.new){
   if(gcMap.containsKey(gc.parent__c) && !gcMap.get(gc.parent__c).Grandparent__r.isEmpty())
       a.Approver__c = gcMap.get(gc.parent__c).Grandparent__r.OwnerID;
}
```